# Change width on click using React

Tags: reactjs, navbar

I am trying to implement a side navigation bar changing the width to show and hide the side navbar. Anyhow, I cannot make the openNav function to work. If I set the initial state to 250 px it shows the navbar and the close function works (it's setting the width to 0). Why the Menu button is not working? What am I missing?

```
class SideNav extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navwidth: 0
        };

        this.openNav = this.openNav.bind(this)
        this.closeNav = this.closeNav.bind(this)

    }
    openNav() {
        this.setState({
            navwidth: '250 px'
        });
    }

    closeNav() {
        this.setState({
            navwidth: 0
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <>
            <button onClick={this.openNav}>Menu</button>
            <div id="mySidenav" className='sidenav' style={{width: `${this.state.navwidth}`}}>
                <a className="closebtn" onClick={this.closeNav}>&times;</a>
                <a href="#">Find data</a>
                <a href="#">Visualize Data</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }

}
class Header extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <SideNav/>
        )
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: I don't think the css is being refreshed. It might be better to use class names ```open``` and ```closed``` with defined width values instead of setting them in ```style```

Comment: That's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified your code,

```
class SideNav extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            navwidth: 0
        };
    }

    openNav = () => {
        this.setState({
            navwidth: '250px'
        });
    }

    closeNav = () => {
        this.setState({
            navwidth: '0px'
        });
    }

    render = () =>
        <>
            <button onClick={this.openNav}>Menu</button>
            <div id="mySidenav" className='sidenav' style={{ width: this.state.navwidth }}>
                <a className="closebtn" onClick={this.closeNav}>&times;</a>
                <a href="#">Find data</a>
                <a href="#">Visualize Data</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
            </div>
        </>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`250 px` should be `250px`. You also don't need to use a templated string here:

`` `${this.state.navwidth}` ``

The simpler:

`this.state.navwidth`

is valid.